# Eclipse Plugin Development: How to highlight syntax in texteditor?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting

Given a java method name, i want to highlight it in the TextEditor. I have reference to the texteditor in ITextEditor.

Comment: What do you mean by highlight (select it, color it, ...?). Do you have the position of the method name?

Comment: @greg-449: By highlight i mean coloring the method. Yes I have the starting and ending line number of the method available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `IMarker` object on a file which the Java editor will show.

```java
IFile file = ... file to mark

IMarker marker = file.createMarker(IMarker.TASK); 

marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, start);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, end);
```

I have used a task marker in this example, but you can use the `org.eclipse.core.resources.markers` extension point to define your own marker.

The 
`org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification` extension point can be used to define the colors and style used to show the markers.

The `org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerUpdaters` extension point can be used to define how markers are updated in an editor as the file is edited.