# Eclipse Plugin Development: Open a popup when marked text is selected in Eclipse TextEditor

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to write a listener which opens a popup when a marked text (marked using custom IMarker) is selected in Eclipse TextEditor.

How to achieve this?

Comment: You can define a popup shown when 'Quick Fix' is pressed

Comment: @greg-449 I don't understand. Can you please elaborate? I am developing an eclipse plugin and I have maked text using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690144/eclipse-plugin-development-how-to-highlight-syntax-in-texteditor/28692566#28692566 . Now I want to open a MessageBox when user clicks on the marked text..

Comment: Doing that would be hard work. The closest you can get to this easily is using the `org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution ` extension point to define a [Quick Fix](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FwrkAdv_markerresolution.htm&cp=2_0_12_11_3_1)